# Help finding this Japanese font please!

Tags: font-identification

Can someone please help identify this JP font? I haven’t had luck on other sites[image]

Comment: Hi. I would normally suggest people looking for Japanese/Chinese fonts use likefont.com - since it has an automated font ID service, however when I visited the site today, there's a virus/security threat on it.  So, maybe not, or at your own risk.  Alternatively perhaps try Japanese Stack Exchange, although I'm not sure if this would be considered on topic, but someone might be able to help you in their chat rooms perhaps.